# st_write() and write_sf() errors

Tags: r

I am trying to write an sf object as a shapefile.  i have tried st_write() and write_sf() both have given Write Error's.  The code snippet and the associated errors received are as below:  I would appreciate any input on the cause.

```
> st_write(twitter_data_sf, "Data/twt.shp", append=F)
Deleting layer `twt' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Writing layer `twt' to data source `Data/twt.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Updating existing layer twt
Writing 68077 features with 29 fields and geometry type Point.
Unknown field name `epoch': updating a layer with improper field name(s)?
Error: Write error
In addition: Warning message:
In abbreviate_shapefile_names(obj) :
  Field names abbreviated for ESRI Shapefile driver
```

```
> write_sf(twitter_data_sf,"PT14.shp", driver = "ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = TRUE)
Unknown field name `in_rply_t_st_': updating a layer with improper field name(s)?
Error: Write error
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In abbreviate_shapefile_names(obj) :
  Field names abbreviated for ESRI Shapefile driver
2: In CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  :
  GDAL Message 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'in_rply_t_st_' to 'in_rply_t_'
3: In CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  :
  GDAL Message 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'in_rply_t_sr_' to 'in_rply__1'
```

```
> st_write(twitter_data_sf, "Data/twt.shp", append=F)

Error: Write error
```

```
> write_sf(twitter_data_sf,"PT14.shp", driver = "ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = TRUE)
Unknown field name `in_rply_t_st_': updating a layer with improper field name(s)?
Error: Write error
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In abbreviate_shapefile_names(obj) :
  Field names abbreviated for ESRI Shapefile driver
2: In CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  :
  GDAL Message 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'in_rply_t_st_' to 'in_rply_t_'
3: In CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  :
  GDAL Message 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'in_rply_t_sr_' to 'in_rply__1'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There might be an issue with some of the columns in your `sf` object. Try removing some of the columns before writing. That way, you should be able to identify the offending columns. Consider sharing a subset of your `sf` object here, otherwise it'll be hard to help you. To share data run `dput(head(twitter_data_sf))` in your R session and paste the output in a code chunk in your question.